# Interconnecting AMQP and XMPP

Tags: python, xmpp, amqp

I'm looking for a way to write a XMPP bot that would listen to a RabbitMQ queue and send messages to the XMPP channel notifying users of any new issues ( already got Nagios sending notifications to RabbitMQ).

I've tried using xmppy and it stopped working and I stumbled across SleekXMPP which looks fairly better.

I'm just wondering if I define a AMQP listener to automatically call the XMPP "send" method in the bot. So it would be listening both on AMQP and XMPP at the same time.

Thank you for your help!

Edit: Would BOSH be much better solution here ?

Comment: It's hard to tell what your question is.  Can you maybe post the code you have so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most interesting part of your solution will be that many libraries in this space assume that they are the only event loop.  You'll either need to put each in its own thread (seemingly easier, but fraught with lurking locking issues), use a non-blocking I/O approach like [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/) (but you'll need an AMQP [library](https://launchpad.net/txamqp)), or extract the socket file descriptors out of each of the libraries you're using and run select() or poll() over them to tell when there is data to read.  Of these three, the Twisted approach seems easiest to me.

BOSH will just make the problem more difficult.  Don't go that way.

Comment: I've played today with this and after 2 hours remebered I'd take a look here.  If anybody is reading this and is in the same issue.  Run the AMQP ( I'm using Pika ) listener, and set the SleekXMPP run as threaded ( xmpp.process(threaded=True) ) process. It's working so far. Both listeners are in the same "file".

Answer (score 1):

This is really quite simple. I suggest that you start by writing an AMQP listener that simply prints out received messages. Once you get that working it should be obvious how to integrate that into an XMPP bot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ejabberd and a xmpp plugin like this https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-xmpp